# How to display express-validator errors using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to use the *express-validator* together with angularjs and html to display validation errors, my problem is im not able to get access to the *errors* variable. See code below.

*routes.js*

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
 var name = req.body.name;
 var email = req.body.email;
 var username = req.body.username;
 var password = req.body.password;
 var password2 = req.body.password2;

 req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('email', 'Email not valid').isEmail();
 req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords does not match').equals(req.body.password);

 var errors = req.validationErrors();

 if(errors){
     res.render('register.html', {
         errors: errors
     });
 } else {
     console.log('no errors');
 }})
```

I found what seems to be the problem, in my *server.js*.
This seem to be causing problems between the express and angular routes, making the express routing fail and therefor not passing data as wanted. See below.

```
app.use(function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/user', users);
```

If i try this, see below.

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/user', users);
app.use(function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});
```

This makes the express routing passing data as i want to, but my angular routing seem to be bugging, once i refresh the page- the view fails to load correctly.

However, i do know how to display this using either ejs or handlebars but this doesnt fit my needs, there should be a way to store the errors with angular and displaying it with html somehow right?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to respond with res.json({errors: errors}) and use errors array on angular side with ng-repeat. Are you facing issues with this?

Comment: @TalhaAwan Thanks a bunch but i tried it by passing in ng-repeat="err in errors", it doesnt fetch anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to use angular's own form validators? It might even be better from a ux perspective because the user will know immediately if their form is valid. It also lets you do cool things like disabling the submit button until the form is valid

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myFormName.$invalid">Submit</button>
```

Adding a simple ng-required to the inputs that are required would take care of most of your needs. Setting input type="email" will validate that email is in the correct format.

The only one that would be kind of tricky might be checking that passwords match but even that can be achieved with an attribute directive.

Comment: No specific reason why, i just want this to work as i wish to, and im also interested in knowing what's causing the problem for the knowledge sake.
Thanks for sharing the solution, as i most likely will continue future projects using angular validation :)